# Inserting an integer into a sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to write a method that takes a sorted array and an integer, creates a new array that is 1 size larger, and inserts the new integer and keeps it sorted.

I've tried a few different implementations and had them to work - but for this specific one, I can't grasp where it's going wrong.

```
    int[] array1 = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8};
    int[] printArray = insert(array1, 5);
```

are the arrays, and the method is

```
public static int[] insert(int[] a, int k) {
    int[] s = new int[a.length + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(k < s[i]) {
            s[i] = k;
            for(int j = i + 1; j < s.length; j++) {
                s[j] = a[i];
                i++;
            }
            return s;
        } else {
            s[i] = a[i];
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

This method prints out 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 0, instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.

Comment: You're right, I mistyped, it originally doesn't print a 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
if(k < s[i]) {
```

to

```
if(k < a[i]) {
```

in line 4.

Comment: How did I miss that.... Been staring at too many a's, k's, j's, and i's that they just all look the same. Thanks

Comment: @Turtle, Good catch !!

Comment: @Turtle I am trying to do it yet again in using 1 for loop, could you take a look at this: http://imgur.com/mp3oMs8

Comment: It is printing 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8. The number after the inserted always comes out 0, then finishes the array correctly.

Comment: @arthur change 'else{ s[]=...; }' directly into 's[]=...'. Hope you get my meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in the following line you are creating an array with all elements zero:

```
int[] s = new int[a.length + 1];
```

`s[0]` to `s[7]` will be `0`.

Your loop counter `i` runs from `0` to `a.length` but the point to note is all the elements of array `s` will be zero. You are comparing `k` with `s[i]` which is zero and for that reason the shifting of arrays never happen (if block never executes).

You need to do two things to fix it.

1. Initialize element zero of `s` with the value of `a[0]`.
2. Compare element with previous element to figure out position to insert.

The final code is:

```
public static int[] insert(int[] a, int k) {
        int[] s = new int[a.length + 1];
        s[0] = a[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
            if(k < s[i-1]) {
                s[i] = k;
                for(int j = i + 1; j < s.length; j++) {
                    s[j] = a[i];
                    i++;
                }
                return s;
            } else {
                s[i] = a[i];
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
```

Now you will get:
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8]`

Comment: This is not correct with values int[] arr = {34,49,71,101,120,180};   int[] printArray = insert(arr, 5);

Answer (score 0):

I would start by using [`Arrays.copyOf(int[], int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int[],%20int%29) to create a new array that is one larger than the input. Then iterate that array until I reached the index that the new value belongs at. Then use [`System.arraycopy(Object,int,Object,int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) to copy the values into the end of the array. That might look something like

```
public static int[] insert(int[] a, int k) {
    int[] s = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] < k) {
            continue;
        }
        System.arraycopy(a, i, s, i + 1, s.length - i - 1);
        s[i] = k;
        break;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Which I tested with [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29) like

```
public static void main(String s[]) throws IOException {
    int[] array1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8 };
    int[] printArray = insert(array1, 5);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(printArray));
}
```

And I get the (expected)

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: So to add John Smith to a phone book you start on page one and read the phone book up to Joe Smith and then add the new entry :)